# Exception safety of std::function initialized by a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++17

The constructor of `std::function` is not declared `noexcept`:

```cpp
template< class F > function( F f );
```

On the other hand, C++ reference mentions the following:

> Does not throw if f is a function pointer or a std::reference_wrapper,
> otherwise may throw std::bad_alloc or any exception thrown by the copy
> constructor of the stored callable object.

Does it mean that the constructor of the following class can be safely declared `noexcept` since I initialize `std::function` with a pointer to a static member function?

```cpp
class Worker
{
public:    
    Worker() noexcept {} // ok?
    void test() { reporter("test"); }
private:
    static void dummy(const std::string& ) {};
    std::function<void (const std::string&)> reporter = &dummy; // doesn't throw an exception?
};

int main()
{
    Worker w;
    w.test();
}
```

And if `std::function` member were constructed from a lambda, declaring the constructor `noexcept` would be wrong?

```cpp
class Worker
{
public:    
    Worker() noexcept {} // bad?
    void test() { reporter("Test"); }
private:
    std::function<void (const std::string&)> reporter = [](const std::string& ){}; // may throw?
};
```

I have also noticed that GCC gives an error when the constructor declared `noexcept` is defaulted, because its exception specification does not match the implicit exception specification, which is `noexcept(false)` due to `std::function` constructor not being declared noexcept.

```cpp
class Worker
{
public:
    Worker() noexcept = default; // this won't compile    
    void test() { reporter("test"); }
private:
    static void dummy(const std::string& ) {};
    std::function<void (const std::string&)> reporter = &dummy;
};
```

Comment: I believe the answer to both your questions is "yes". The compiler can't automatically detect that the constructor can't throw because the constructor of `std::function` is not declared `noexcept`, it's only described as sometimes non-throwing in the prose of the standard. I suppose it might have been possible to provide several overloads of `std::function` constructor, using SFINAE techniques to separate those that can be marked `noexcept` from those that cannot be, but for better or worse the standard doesn't require that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that the constructor of the following class can be safely declared `noexcept` since I initialize `std::function` with a pointer to a static member function?

Note that it's always "safe" to declare a function `noexcept`. The program will terminate if an exception is thrown, but it isn't undefined behavior.

But yes, in your case, no exceptions should be thrown, so no termination of the program should happen. The standard says: "*Throws*: Nothing if `f` is ... a function pointer. ..."

> And if `std::function` member were constructed from a lambda, declaring the constructor `noexcept` would be wrong?

Yes, it'd be "wrong" in the sense you want (the program will terminate if it throws), because a lambda isn't a function pointer. Instead, prefix the lambda with the unary `operator+` to make it a function pointer:

```
std::function<void (const std::string&)> reporter = +[](const std::string& ){};
```

And I'd probably mention this in a comment, in particular if you did not comment why the constructor is `noexcept`.

> I have also noticed that GCC gives an error when the constructor declared `noexcept` is defaulted

The latest versions of both GCC and Clang do not give an error, so if that is true it is perhaps a Defect Report that was issued on the standard.

Comment: The interaction between `noexcept` and `default` was fixed (retroactively) in [P1286R2](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1286r2.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference Davis! It seemed one of those cases, yeah.